# Multiple Categories on Catlist using name function

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

Hi there I am hoping that someone can help me with the "plugin-list-category-post" plugin.

I am using this shortcode in a post to activate the plugin

```
[catlist name='Audi' name='Cadillac' template='category-display-template' excerpt='yes' thumbnail='yes' numberposts='2']
```

In the result it shows me two listings of 'cadillac' but it ignores the audi name tag...

Is it possible to do it this way? or do I absolutely need to use the category id tag, for multiple posts? - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get multiple categories working on [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/), you need to separate them by comma like this:
`[catlist id=1,2]` for Category ID, and `[catlist name='Audi,Cadillac']` for Category Name. Please note that multiple categories for the `name` parameter was just added on version 0.20.5.